# Dataflow in Python not showing output collection from Pubsub subscription

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I have a Dataflow job written in Python. It's very simple, only read from a subscription, apply Fixed Window and then write into GCS.

The problem is after reading from the subscription, the FixedWindow doesn't show any output collection.

I have been trying anything without luck.

Here's my code

```py
import apache_beam as beam
import argparse
import logging
import apache_beam.transforms.window as window
from apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub import ReadFromPubSub
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import StandardOptions

def run(argv=None):

    """Main entry point; defines and runs the wordcount pipeline."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--input',
                        dest='input',
                        required=True,
                        default='gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt',
                        help='Input file to process.')
    parser.add_argument('--output',
                        dest='output',
                        required=True,
                        default='gs://dataflow-samples/',
                        help='Output file to write results to.')
    parser.add_argument('--topic',
                        dest='topic',
                        required=True,
                        help='Topic for message.')
    parser.add_argument('--subscription',
                        dest='subscription',
                        required=True,
                        help='Subscription for message.')
    parser.add_argument('--entity_type',
                        dest='entity_type',
                        required=True,
                        help='Entity Type for message.')
    parser.add_argument('--event_type',
                        dest='event_type',
                        required=True,
                        help='Event Type for message.')                        
    parser.add_argument('--outputFilenamePrefix',
                        dest='outputFilenamePrefix',
                        required=True,
                        help='Output Filename Prefix Type for message.')   
    parser.add_argument('--outputFilenameSuffix',
                        dest='outputFilenameSuffix',
                        required=True,
                        help='Output Filename Suffix Type for message.') 

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
    pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming= True
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

    if known_args.subscription:
        messages = (p 
                | ReadFromPubSub(subscription=known_args.subscription, with_attributes=True))
    else:
        messages = (p 
                | ReadFromPubSub(subscription=known_args.topic, with_attributes=True))

    (messages 
            | beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(120))
            | beam.io.WriteToText(known_args.output + known_args.outputFilenamePrefix, 
                                    file_name_suffix=known_args.outputFilenameSuffix,
                                    num_shards=1))

    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

The idea is to save the results in the provided bucket. I've been reading that some features like Window in unbounded data are not yet supported. In that case, the only solution will be doing this using Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WriteToText is not supported in python, when writing to GCS. This would work in Java as you discuss. Or you could write records to a separate IO, like BigQuery.

[Supported IO Builts ins](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/)